# Limit response from API call

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I'm using the [Dark sky](https://darksky.net/dev/docs) API, to request the hourly weather. This returns an array with 48 data objects. I'm then mapping these data blocks to my react app with

```
{this.state.hourly.map(hour => {
        return (
          <div className="text-center">
            <div key={hour.time} className="key col-md-1">
              <div className="">{this._getTime(hour.time)}</div><br />
              <div className=""><canvas className={hour.icon} width="64" height="64">
              </canvas></div><br />
              <div className=""><strong>{this._roundingNumber(hour.temperature)}&deg;</strong></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

However i want to either limit the data blocks from the API call, or end the map function after, lets say 8 data objects.

So my question is: How do I limit the API response? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

If that's not possible, is there a way I can end the `.map` function after a specified number of objects passing through?

Comment: You're looking for `.slice()`.

Comment: try this.state.hourly.slice(0,8).map ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try that